# Javascript variable's “Value” property does not come up on the Intellisense Insted show Value of

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello I am new to java scripts.

I wanted to implement this function in my ASP.net webpage. I used a separate .js file in project and called to it from the header section of the asp.net web page.

Here is the function that I want to implement.

```
function userValid() 
{
    var Name;
    Name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    if (Name == '') 
    {
       alert("Please Enter Name");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But the probelem is when after typing `document.getElementById("txtName")`.   ( Its only shows `valueOf()` instead of value.

This is the textbox code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="250" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter what it shows it is not great help in java-script in visual studio.
So you are doing the right thing.

Also you should be using `ClientId` instead of direct "txtName"

```
 Name = document.getElementById("<%= txtName.ClientID %>").value;
```

More detail on ClientId is here
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

More reference of using intelligence in visual studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx

Comment: Yes it working when I implement the function with in my aspx file. But you cant cant call it from external .js. Finally I found solutions to how to call it. You have to set clientIDmode to static or else you have to pass control's clientID to external.js. Thanks so much Shekhar. Learnt lot.